# I am Getting Slow Response with Sequelize Pagination for Larger Offset

Tags: node.js, api, pagination, sequelize.js, node-modules

I have Huge Data regarding the Product I guess 140 fields split into different Tables.
It's Working fine when I select the first page of data but as I go for the 19th or 20th page it gets very slow.

When I Request for Page=1 and pageSize=100 I get response in 35seconds.
But As I increase the Page Numbers say 19
It Responds in 8min or even More.
Guide me to Some Optimal and More Professional Way.
Any Hint would be Appreciated.

## My API Handler is Something Like

````
    const page = req.query.page || 1
    const pageSize = req.query.pageSize || 30
    try {
        const data = await BasicProductDetail.findAll({
            include: [
                { model: AdditionalProductDetail },
                { model: Catalog },
                { model: ImageDetail },
                { model: Manufacturer },
                { model: Measurement },
                { model: PriceAndCost },
                { model: ProductClass },
                { model: Selling },
                { model: UPC },
                { model: Usage }
            ],
            limit : pageSize,
            offset : (page - 1) * pageSize,
            order : [ ['id', 'ASC']]
        })
        const count = await BasicProductDetail.count({ })
        res.json({
            data: data,
            count : count
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return res.status(500).send(Something Went Wrong!!!)
    }
}```
=================================
````

Answer (score 0):

couple of suggestions.

- Instead of using two different queries, you could use findAndCountAll method. It will return you both the rows data and the count.
- Make sure each model has proper indexing done
- Instead of pulling all the attributes, try specifying set of attributes which are needed.